# Modify react child components state for storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a react Component that I am trying to add to a storybook.  It has child components that have component state which changes the way the component displays.  I would like to set that component state to show in my storybook.  What is the best way to achieve this ?

```
class ParentComponent extends PureComponent<ParentComponentProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent />
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends PureComponent<ChildComponentProps> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleOnBlur = this.handleOnBlur.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isValid: true
    };
  }

  handleOnBlur() {
    this.setState({
      isValid: isInputValid()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
          placeholder="eg. 12345"
          validationMessage={'not a valid input'}
          isInvalid={this.state.isValid}
          onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

And Storybook code looks like this at the moment

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent';

export default { title: 'UpdateChildComponent' };

export const FieldValidationShowing = (state) => {
  const { store, updateState } = mockStore;
  updateState(state);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ParentComponent />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

The above code is a sample of what I am doing.

Comment: It would be better if you add some code.

Comment: @Erick updated to include a sample

Comment: I assume you were not able to find any answer, right?